# Can Ransomware effect the Linux OS?

Tags: security, encryption, malware

Recently, [The Hacker News](http://thehackernews.com/) stated the following:

> Ransomware threat has emerged as one of the biggest threats to internet users in recent times. Typically, a Ransomware malware encrypts all files on victim’s computer with a strong cryptographic algorithm, then demand a ransom to be paid in Bitcoin (range between $200 and $10,000).
>   Cryptowall is currently among the most widespread and sophisticated family of Ransomware backed by a very robust back-end infrastructure.

[Source](http://thehackernews.com/2015/11/cryptowall-ransomware-malware.html)

Would this work on Linux?
If it can, what could I do to help secure my system against these attacks?

Comment: What would "this" be? Cryptowall?

Comment: Back up your system.  If you get hit by this, reinstall it, and don't go back to that website.

Comment: Is it possible, of course it is possible. Best defense is to back up your data, as @OrganicMarble suggests.

Comment: And the ***BEST*** solution: don't run random programs, don't randomly install things, be sane with what you do on the internet.

Comment: If you're looking for a port, you should contact the OEM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would this work on Linux?

Why not? The general principle is applicable to Linux, the specific means might be different from common Windows attacks.

> If it can, what could I do to help secure my system against these attacks?

Don't run random executables off the internet. Keep your system updated. The usual.

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways, but I_love_you.deb attachment is the easiest method.

To secure computer you should backup your data both locally and on a cloud. On computer we have (a) large-and-cheap data like movies and (b) compact and precious work related data (scripts, reports, presentations). Former can be saved on USB drive (keep it unplugged, when not syncing). The latter should be emailed to yourself daily and saved on CD-R, not CD-RV, not on USB. CD-R might sound dated, but it works.

Is it safe to transfer data from infected Windows to Linux if I don't use sudo?
It depends. If you make sure that Linux OS is a primary master then it might be. Otherwise infected Windows OS can "patch" your Linux files, then boot your Linux. Sounds futuristic, but I've experienced it.